# rails active storage wrong url - 301 status

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

Using Active Storage in order to attach an `image` to an `article`

in `storage.yml` :

```
local:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("storage") %>
```

`article.rb`:

```rb
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :auteur
  has_one_attached :image
```

in the form for adding an article :

```rb
<%= f.file_field :image %>
```

In  article_controller.rb:

```rb
def hop
    @auteur = Auteur.find(params[:auteur_id])
    @article = @auteur.articles.new(article_params)
    @article.publie = params[:publie].to_s
    @article.slug = Article.to_slug(@article.titre)
    @article.save
    redirect_to adm_auteur_tous_articles_url
  end
```

Doing this, the image get uploaded to `storage/es/ul/esulvqpj2apfcqx41hwdtnchd5y4`

(and that's correct as I can see the image there in the MacOs finder window)

but in the view, I do this:

`<%= image_tag(@article.image)  if @article.image.attached? %>`

Image not showing up because the url of the image is:

`http://localhost:3000/rails/active_storage/blobs/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBCZz09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--661c66c418b20fc46350823faaac7124c25138dd/chat.jpg`

That causes a `301 moved permanently` status.

So the image is not showing up.

Comment: You're right: I removed the explicit attachment in the controller (also doesn't show up in the question any longer). I do other things too, such as creating a slug (nothing to do with active storage)

Answer (score 0):

removing this line from routes did the trick (I had it as last line ot routes.rb:

```rb
 get '*path' => redirect('/')
```